# How to resolve typescript error 'possibly undefined object'? - ts(2532)

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a helper function (firebase cloud functions) to attach a payment source to a Stripe customer account.

Here's my code:

```
export const attachSource = async(uid: string, source: string) => {

    const customer = await getOrCreateCustomer(uid);

    const existingSource = customer.sources.data.filter(s => s.id === source).pop(); 

    if (existingSource) {
        return existingSource;
    } 
    else {
        await stripe.customers.createSource(customer.id, { source: source });
        // update default
        return await stripe.customers.update(customer.id, { default_source: source });
    }
}
```

I tried optional chaining `customer.sources?.data` but this throws several errors.

Also tried wrapping it in an `if` statement like this:

```
if (customer && customer.sources && customer.sources.data) {
    const existingSource = customer.sources.data.filter(s => s.id === source).pop()

    if (existingSource) {
        return existingSource;
    } else {
        await stripe.customers.createSource(subscriber.id, { source: source});
        // update default
        return await stripe.customers.update(subscriber.id, {default_source: source});
    }
}
```

This causes the following error: `Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)`

Can't use `!` to silence the problem because a payment source may not be present in Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `if` statement is missing an `else` so that the enclosing function always returns a value:

```
if (customer && customer.sources && customer.sources.data) {
}
else {
    // what do you want to return here?
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good question - not sure what needs to be returned... 